# Android Studio: save project version as a backup

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm working on my android app, and now is perfectly working.
How can I save the whole project so that if I make changes and want to get back to the previous state I can get everything back as it was.

For example:
I get my app working and I call such state: version 1.0.
To improve my app I modify the various file and get to: version 1.3.
Now, I made a mess with version 1.3 and want to get back, how can I get to version 1.0?

Comment: Use a GIT repository.

Comment: @SBerg413 Android newbie here.  If I use a Git repository do I assume correctly my app code is saved in the cloud on Git's servers?  If yes, should I therefore be worried about hackers getting access to/stealing my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the same purpose, a system called the **Version Control System(VCS)** was founded. These help you to keep and maintain versions of your code. `Git`, `Mercurial` are some VCS. `Git` is the most widely used one. It allows more than just maintaining versions. It helps to:

- Keep snapshots of code.
- See changes across the snapshots(commits)
- Make branches and try experimental features.
- Automatically merge branches and letting you fix any conflicts.

So I strongly suggest you to learn to use Git. You can find some good tutorials here:

```
[Udacity course][1]
[Tutorials Point][2]
[Attlassian Git tutorial][3]
```

Comment: @S Praveen Kumar  Android newbie here. If I use a Git repository do I assume correctly my app code is saved in the cloud on Git's servers? If yes, should I therefore be worried about hackers getting access to/stealing my code?

Comment: @S Praveen Kumar  Do you have the links to the above 3 tutorials?  They are not live, clickable links.

Comment: The links 
https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/git

Comment: Git can be used offline as well as online. The commits you make will be stored in the local repository(On your disk). When you push it, it goes into a remote repository(online). You can choose whether and when the commits should be pushed to remote(online). This remote repository is provided to you by various services like GitHub, Bitbucket, etc. When you create a repository on any of these services, you can choose to keep it private or public( some services requires a paid subscription for using private repo). The code is ultimately stored in their  servers.

Comment: @AJW Regarding hackers getting access to your code totally depends on the security implemented by the service. In general use any reputed one like GitHub or BitBucket(But Github is not free for private repo). If you choose to you can just use Git offline without a remote repository.

Answer (score 5):

Use GIT and create branch or tag for your project version. You can check out to any previous version of project where you committed out any change or tagged. Better you check out tutorial like http://www.tutorialspoint.com/git/

Comment: Android newbie here. If I use a Git repository do I assume correctly my app code is saved in the cloud on Git's servers? If yes, should I therefore be worried about hackers getting access to/stealing my code?

Answer (score 3):

Version control is the way to go.
look up [Git](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git).
[github](https://github.com/) has awesome tutorials

Comment: Android newbie here. If I use a Git repository do I assume correctly my app code is saved in the cloud on Git's servers? If yes, should I therefore be worried about hackers getting access to/stealing my code?

Comment: To worry or not to worry that is question that only you can answer for yourself. I'd recommend meditation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, VCS is the way to go but as many might have worries like I did that someone might steal your code from those repositories, the github is a public repository and thus others can access it, to have a private repo you need to pay. So, better use other services like Bitbucket that provides private repo for free.